# Setting up Amazon Webservices for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've been trying to set up a web server using EC2 on Amazon web services. 
Using the `appstack-nginx-passenger-ree` AMI, I tried to set up the server.

I put my ruby files in `/opt/sites` and I installed *passenger* and *apache2-dev* & *apace2-mpm-fork*.
I had to set up the apache config file. 
Afterwards what should I do?

How do I set the path file of the ruby files and deploy them?
How can I start up the server and be able to look at it?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you start up apache (which should show you a default welcome page on your the IP of you box (if you have opened up the firewall)), then setup the path to your ruby project in your `httpd.conf` file.

[Here's a guide that might help you out](http://enbake.com/setting-up-rails-3-stack-on-an-amazon-ec2-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Paul, your link is broken, the corrected link for the guide is this Setting up [Rails 3 on Amazon EC2 instance](http://blog.enbake.com/setting-up-rails-3-stack-on-an-amazon-ec2-instance/)